# Xamarin iOS : How to detect the tableview scroll

Tags: xamarin.ios

I want to detect the scroll of tableview in my class. I used decelerationEnded method of UITableViewDelegate but it got crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using a UITableViewSource assigned to your UITableView.Source property. You no longer require a delegate class, you can override all of the necessary methods within the source, which is the currently preferred method of achieving the result your after. You are most likely looking to override the method called 'Scrolled' within the UITableViewSource. However I would suggest making use of 'DecelerationEnded' as well if you're trying to do something depending on if your scroll view is at the 'bottom' or 'top' of the UITableViews content (That's just a little tip based off of some experience with this in a recent project.)